# Doctrine2 - persist entity with accociations without fetching associated entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 2 entities: ProfileContact and Profile. There is association between them.

```
class ProfileContact {

    /**
     * @var integer $profileContactId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="profile_contact_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $profileContactId;

    /**
     * @var text $description
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", 
     * nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var Profile
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Profile")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="profile_id", 
     * nullable=false, 
     * onDelete="CASCADE", referencedColumnName="profile_id")
     * })
     */
    private $profile;
}
```

.

```
class Profile {

    /**
     * @var integer $profileId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="profile_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $profileId;
}
```

Of course there are appropriate setters and getters.

How should I create and persist ProfileContact entity to associated with existing profile but not fetched earlier by D2? I don't want to ask database for entire Profile entity.

```
    $profile = $this->getProfileRepository()->find(2);  //I want to avoid this
    $item = new \Alden\BonBundle\Entity\ProfileContact();
    $item->setProfile($profile);
    $item->setDescription('abc');
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $em->persist($item);
    $em->flush();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$item->setProfile($em->getReference('Profile', 2));
```